# I can't cd to my flashdrive

Tags: linux, debian, files, filesystems, mount

After using the command `cd /media/pi/Pendrive`, I got an error:

`bash: cd: /media/pi/Pendrive: Transport endpoint is not connected`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this error by unmounting and remounting the mountpoint.

Then try this command:

> ```
> sudo fusermount -uz /data
> mount /data
> ```

```
Attribution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24966676/transport-endpoint-is-not-connected
```

Comment: after mounting, my mounting point folder turned into "inode/x-corrupted type"